# How to handle multiple exceptions in @exeptionhandler and response body?

Tags: spring, spring-security, exceptionhandler, spring-web

Should I create an extra method with org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException as parameter?

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AccessDeniedExceptionAdvice {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    @Autowired
    private ErrorResponseMapperService errorResponseMapper;

    @ExceptionHandler({ com.mycomp.myapp.platform.common.exception.AccessDeniedException.class
                      , org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException.class }) // <-- Here i have added an extra exeption
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorResponseDto accessDenied(com.mycomp.myapp.platform.common.exception.AccessDeniedException.class ex) {
        log.error("Access denied", ex);
        return errorResponseMapper.createErrorReponseDto(null, "Access Denied",
                MyAppErrorCodesEnumDto.MY_APP_UNAUTHORIZED_EXCEPTION);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code above didn't work?

Comment: No it didn't work, that is why i'm asking :)

Comment: Did you get an error or can you elaborate what didn't work?

Comment: seems like it ditn't trigger at all